# select the last element having some style property

Tags: css

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border : 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr class="heade_class">
            <th>#</th>
            <th style="display:table-cell">First Name</th>
            <th style="display:table-cell">Last Name</th>
            <th style="display:none">Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td style="display:none">@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td style="display:none">@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td style="display:none">@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> code here is just example here note that th and tr are dynamically set with the values.

hi guys i wan to select only last th of the  which having the style"display:table-cell" property only

now i have tried little bit with using last-child
here i can get the all th with the style"display:table-cell" property only but could not find last th among them

using only css

```css
   .heade_class th[style*="display: table-cell"]:last-child {
 
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it cannot be achieved unless using JavaScript is an option.

Comment: @Mimi if i want to use the javascript then i have already made it

Answer (score 2):

In short, you cannot do this with CSS alone.

**The Problem**

First of all, spaces are important. You cannot have a space after `th` and the style attribute must match exactly the same as the style defined in the HTML. So for it to be valid it should be as follows:

```
.heade_class th[style*="display:table-cell"]
```

However, you still won't get what you want because `last-child` doesn't work as you think. In order for it to match it must be the last child, not just the last element that matches your other specification.

So if you consider this:

```
.heade_class th[style*="display:table-cell"]:last-child
```

What it means is as follows:

1. Is a `th` element
2. **And** the `style` attribute contains `display:table-cell`
3. **And** it is the last child element

For this you will notice none of your elements match all three conditions and that is why it doesn't work.

**Other Options**

Some other options, but they are probably not quite what you are looking for:

You could try `nth-last-child` as follows, but it relies on you knowing how many elements are going to be hidden after it, which probably isn't what you want:

```
.heade_class th[style*="display:table-cell"]:nth-last-child(2)
```

An alternative, depending on how you render your HTML, would be to either omit the hidden ones completely, or change the hidden ones to `td`. If you change them to `td` then you can use `last-of-type` like so:

```
.heade_class th:last-of-type
```

But you may want to check the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-of-type) for that before using it.

Comment: So the answer is a big NO.

Comment: @musefan i have already tried it's not working without space and with space so **it's not working**

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara: Yes, I am telling you why it doesn't work because you don't seem to understand

Comment: @musefan i can use :last-of-type that finds the last one th but couldn't find the visible one